# Maintain aspect ratio and center text inside

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div responsive. I like the way it works when the screen changes: It works like an img, it keep some proportion between width and height. The problem is the text inside. How could I center the text, horizontal and vertical? At the same time, it would be good if there is some distance between text and the limit of the div. Remember: all that in a responsive environment.

To check and play:http://jsfiddle.net/xkr6v9yh/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="small">some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}


#small {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;/* 50% of width of container */

    color: white;
    text-align: center;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: 1- center horizontal and vertical, 2- with a margin or padding when the screen changes

Comment: do you look for something with display:flex : http://jsfiddle.net/xkr6v9yh/3/ ?  Or display:table/table-cell will do very easily

Comment: @harry: when the screen changes, the text could be in 2,3... lines of text. And css3 does not have a good browser support yet

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/xkr6v9yh/4/?

Comment: @Nrc: That approach would support even if no. of lines of text increases. Transforms are supported from IE9 up and IE8 support is being dropped from Jan by Microsoft themselves.

Comment: @harry: I do not understand, in your example text is not centered

Comment: @harry: check your fiddle when the screen is small

Answer (score 0):

Applied table and table-cell property to align the text in the middle.

```css
#wrapper {
 position: relative;
 margin:0 auto;
 background: red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}


#small {
 width: 100%;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="small">some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The table solution needs a specific height to work. I cannot use this because the div must behave like an img in a responsive environment

Comment: @Nrc could you give us your ratio ? or see my answer and  set your value to set the proper ratio you look for.

Comment: The div behaves like an img 600pxx 300px. I suppose this is ratio 2:1?

Comment: @Nrc okay, this would be a vertical padding of 50% . vertical % padding or margin takes parent's width as reference. i updated my answer with this value

Answer (score 0):

as other answer but with a ratio setted: [codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwmePW)

```css
#wrapper {
  background: red;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 75%;
  /* whatever you want to start with*/
  color: white;
}
#small {
  background: blue;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 1em;
}
/* set here a basic ratio to the container */

#wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  padding-top: 50%;
}
/* FURTHER ? */

/* give a max-width to content ? */

#small>* {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="small">
    <p>some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some tex</p>
    <p>some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text, some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```